# Alternative to 5-speed twist shifter for Shimano Nexus 5-speed IGH?

Tags: shifter, internally-geared-hub, nexus, alfine

I'm going to buy a SG-C7000-5D / SG-C7050-5D and don't want to use the twist shifter. Unfortunately there aren't many 5-speed flat bar shifters around theses days. I've searched for alfine shifters, but there's no 5-speed version, so also no corresponding shifter available..

Luckily I found the Shimano SL-5S50 for Nexus, but it's discontinued and I can't find it anywhere in Europe. Since the Indicator Unit (Black, Y-6WX98020) and 7-speed version (SL-7S50) are still available, the following questions came into my mind:

- Can I simply swap the Indicator Unit of SL-7S50 with a SL-5S50?
- Is there another 5-speed flat bar shifter that has the same "cable pull-distance"? Maybe even without indicator?

[image]

Comment: I don't have conclusive answers to either question, but I think the real answer is you'll just have to pay international shipping. Nexus 5 is pretty weird. There may be some physical compatibility between the two indicators, or not, but the indicators are controlled by the mechanism in Shimano shifters, not vice versa. If they do phyisically fit together, the indicator will just wind up in random spots in its range since the cable pull won't correspond to where the numbers are.

Comment: I was not even aware there was a nexus 5 speed.

Comment: @Criggie the Nexus 5 is rather new, announced in 2010 or something like that

Answer (score -1):

Another option may be to mount a [grip shift lever](https://integrated-3d-products.myshopify.com/products/gripshiftlever-help-kids-grip-shift-bikes-with-ease) onto the twist shifter. My 5 year old son uses this on his twist shifter, and he loves it.

[image: Image of grip shift lever, a simple handle with a clamp ring that attaches to the twist shifter]

Comment: Nice idea but in my option this is not an acceptable solution to my question.. This simply does not accommodate for what a real flat bar shift would offer in terms of comfort and reliable shifting.